# TV Show About People Who Make Deals With The Devil

Tags: story-identification, tv

I remember watching a show on Hulu (90% sure it was on Hulu, but when I checked a list of their original programming I couldn't find it) that involved people meeting with a supernatural figure that acted as a middleman between the people and God. I don't know if the figure was a demon or an angel. It might have been ambiguous. The middleman would give them a task in exchange for his help.  In one episode he told an old lady to build a bomb, and in another he told a man to surveil a kid. I believe the stories were also interconnected. When the old lady's bomb went off, I think the man was able to save the kid's life because he was close by watching. That's all I remember.

Comment: Do the people make their deals sitting across from the man in a booth at a diner? I can't identify that, but if it's that I saw teasers for it somewhere back in the day.

Comment: Yes, I believe it was a diner.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, that's it. It's called [The Booth at the End](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Booth_at_the_End). It was originally on the FX cable network, but may have been on Hulu afterward. The Wikipedia description says:

> The series follows the fates of an apparently random group of strangers who each enter into a Faustian pact with a mysterious figure, the Man (Berkeley), who they believe possesses the power to grant any wish, in return for which they must carry out a task he assigns them - hence the series tagline, "How far would you go to get what you want?" The series is notable for its ingenious mise-en-scene, in which the dramatic action is entirely conveyed through a series of conversations between the Man and his clients, which all take place in the eponymous "booth at the end" of an archetypal American diner.

Comment: Thanks! This is definitely it. How did you find it?

Comment: I had a dim memory that the word 'booth' was in the title.

Comment: Again, thanks! Have a great weekend!